# Looking up array-valued keys by deep comparison instead of strict equality in ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm in the process of porting some code that used the [hashmap](https://github.com/flesler/hashmap) library to ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). However, I'm running into an issue that my existing maps are keyed with arrays. Come lookup time, equivalent arrays are generated and used as lookup keys. Using `HashMap`, this was fine, since complex keys are hashed in a way that's equivalent to deep comparison. ES6's `Map`, on the other hand, performs strict equality comparison on the keys.

My old method of looking up keys:

```
var h = new HashMap();
var k = [1,2,3];
h.set(k, 'foo');
h.has([1,2,3]) // returns true
```

Under ES6, that method doesn't work, due to strict equality comparison.

```
var m = new Map();
var k = [1,2,3];
m.set(k, 'foo');
m.has([1,2,3]) // returns false
```

Is there a way to force a given comparison function, or overload `get()` in a way that will look up complex keys by deep comparison instead of strict equality? I haven't been able to create a `Map` subclass that does so without a linear search through the keys, completely destroying any efficiency gains I'd've gotten from using a native type in the first place.

Comment: No, unfortunately there is not.

Comment: Thanks for the dupe! I'd been looking here for about a half hour, and hadn't searched for "hash" in context, so I entirely missed that.

Comment: Yeah, for a hashmap you not only need a custom equality function but also a hashing method. And JS has neither :-/

Comment: I guess I'm sticking with the third-party lib then...
/me unstages changes